# MVC Model not updating View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have an MVC application which is also using Telerik controls. View has the following Kendo Drop down list:

```
                  <%= Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("agents")
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .Enable(Model.IsAdmin)          
      .DataSource(source =>
           {
               source.Read(read => read.Action("GetUsers", "Schedule"));                                      
           })
       .Value(Model.SelectedUser)
      .Events(e => e.Select("SelectionChanged"))
```

%>

When the list is changed it fires the event SelectionChanged which does an Ajax call to method UpdateUser on the controller.

```
     function SelectionChanged(e) {
         var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
         var passeddata = dataItem.Value;
         $.ajax({
             url: '/Schedule/UpdateUser',
             data: { user: passeddata },
             success: function () {
             }
         });

         var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
         scheduler.dataSource.read();
     }
```

On my controller The method updates the model and sets a value in the session then calls the Schedule Action to reload the view.

```
    public ActionResult UpdateUser(string user)
    {
        _taskService.SelectedUser = user;
        Session["ScheduledUser"] = user;
        return View("Schedule");
    }

    public ActionResult Schedule()
    {
        ModelState.Clear();

        //Check to ensure the user is not logged out
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["LoggedInUser"].ToString()))
                return RedirectToAction("LogOut", "Account");
        }
        catch (Exception) { RedirectToAction("LogOut", "Account"); }


        var timeOffset = Session["TimeOffset"].ToString();
        _taskService.TimeOffset = Convert.ToInt32(timeOffset);

        //Set the last viewed schedule   
        _taskService.IsAdmin = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["IsAdmin"].ToString());
        ViewData["PageName"] = "Schedule";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_taskService.SelectedUser))
        {
            _taskService.SelectedUser = Session["LoggedInUser"].ToString();
        }

        _taskService.UserWorkgroups = GetLoggedOnUserWorkgroups(_taskService.SelectedUser);

        Session["ScheduledUser"] = _taskService.SelectedUser;
        MessageHandler.NewNote("Loading schedule for user: " + _taskService.SelectedUser);
        UpdateModel(_taskService);
        return View(_taskService);
    }
```

The problem I have is when loaded the view populates an entry on my model called UserWorkgroups and displays the value:

```
          <h4 style="color: #30068b; text-align: Center;">Workgroups: <%:Model.UserWorkgroups%></h4>
```

Once the drop down has changed it should update the workgroups for the new user and amend the display on the view. I have gone through the code and it is firing the Schedule() action result and populating the correct user and workgroups however the view does not change the workgroups it shows the original value.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: 1) You should update the `UpdateUser` to `RedirectToAction` instead of returning view `return RedirectToAction("Schedule")` 2) In Ajax success handler, there is no code to update the returned html to any existing input/div control.

Comment: Tried changing to redirect but it is still not updating the UI with the workgroup name. What is strange is the Drop down list can see the changed Model data but not the Header item

Comment: Do you have any code in `success: function () { }` code block?

Comment: No I don't have any code in there. Should I have something in there to refresh the page again?